# When Changing Password in AD through ldap and SSl Connection,its not creating InitialLdapContext ,exception:connection reset

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to implement change password function in my site using LDAP. 
Problem :-When Changing Password in AD(server) through ldap and SSl Connection,its  not creating `InitialLdapContext` ,getting exception:connection reset.attached the screenshots for exception.added the  certification also .

I have checked the port also. It is connecting via telnet.

Any help appreciated.

```
public String changePassword(String username,String currentPassword, String newPassword, String 
confirmPassword) {

    String retVal="failed";
    String domain = "edw.obc.co.in";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String LdapUserName="CN="+username ; //g

    //+ "ou=users" + "dc=edw,dc=obc,dc=co,dc=in" ; g


    String DomainUseName = username+"@" + domain;
    prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://172.xx.xx.xx:636");
    prop.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");
    //prop.put("javax.net.ssl.truststore","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
    //prop.put("javax.net.ssl.truststorePassword","changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.truststore", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.truststorePassword", "changeit");


    //prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,LdapUserName);
    prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"winadmin");
    //prop.put("LDAP_BASEDN","ou=edw,dc=obc,dc=co.in");
    prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"wipro@123");
    //prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"wipro@123");

    prop.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");
    try
    {
         LdapContext ctx =new InitialLdapContext(prop,null);

         System.out.print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

         SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();

            searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            NamingEnumeration objects = null;

         try {

                objects=ctx.search("cn="+username+",ou=Users,"+"dc=edw"+","+"dc=obc"+","+"dc=co"+","+"dc=in", String.format("(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccounName=%s))", LdapUserName),searchControls);

            }
            catch(NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          String theUserName="cn="+username+",ou=Users";


          // Perform the update


         ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
         String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
         byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
         mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,new BasicAttribute("userpassword", newUnicodePassword));

         ctx.modifyAttributes(theUserName, mods);
         retVal="success";
         System.out.println("Changed Password for user successfull");
         ctx.close();
    }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
              System.err.println("Problem changing password: " + e);
    }



    return retVal;
}

private static byte[] getPasswordByteArray(String password)

{

    String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";

    try

    {

        return quotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

    }

    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)

    {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/jwilleke/Examples-JNDI/blob/master/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java

For Connection Reset by Peer it would appear there is an issue with the SSL/TLS Connection

Answer (score 0):

The protocol to change password must be `ldaps` not `ldap`:

```
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://172.xx.xx.xx:636");
                                ^^^^
```

---

Also, consider replacing:

```
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,new BasicAttribute("userpassword", newUnicodePassword));
```

with:

```
ModificationItem[] mods = {new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", oldPasswordBytes)),
                           new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newPasswordBytes))};
```

to be able to change user's password without admin privileges on Active Directory.

Comment: I tried this but still getting javax.naming.CommunicationException:Simple bind Failed :172.XX.XX.XX:636[Root Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSlException:Connection reset]